# Add, list and remove items from a UITableView in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiview, swift2

I need to create an app that uses a UITableView within a UIView. So I created my scketch the app, and added what he needed. In UIView has a button (which will be used to add items) a tableView (to list items). I created a SubClass of UITableView to add, list and remove items in the tableView.

I tried to add some code like this:
`func override tableView (tableView: UITableView ?, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)`. But the result is a mistake because not being in a UITableViewController.

My question is:
**How do I add, list and remove items from a UITableView within a UIView, without using a UITableViewController?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@RP's answer is correct for your approach, but your approach is wrong. You almost never want to subclass `UITableView`. You want to make your `UIViewController` the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate`.

Here's a [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/) that describes how you should be adding a table view to a standard view controller.

Answer (score 1):

When you subclass your `UITableView`, your subclass will have to conform to `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols (based on your application's requirement). These protocols provide necessary methods for your subclass including but not limited to `tableView (tableView: UITableView?, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)` method.

Refer to this [Apple tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson7.html) which provides further details. Refer to the "Display the Data" section

Comment: You know the best way to interact with the UITableView?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "best way to interact with UITableView". I have provided a link to an Apple Tutorial page.

Comment: Sorry, as I said at the end of the question, I need to use a UITableView in UIViewController. The tutorial Apple has the focus to TableViewController.

Comment: You would find a lot of resources if you did some search. To get you started, this [post](http://www.weheartswift.com/how-to-make-a-simple-table-view-with-ios-8-and-swift/) should help